# Gradle keeps forcing download to 4.6

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have an android project, lately giving me headache. Because it keeps show a message:

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 4.6.
```

And it doesn't do anything because of that. I've tried changing distribuitionUrl to 5.4.1, no success. Tried invalidating cache and restart, and every time I do this, it keeps forcing download version to 4.6 even deleting all 4.6. that I find in my project.
I'm too resistant to question but searching related problems and not working I got to this. Also haven't find anything in gradle official site that could help me. Has anyone knows what's going on and why does this happen and what can I do to solve this?

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

buildscript

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete build.gradle file so that people can understand what's your issue actually

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I solved by deleting the .idea folder of the project and rebuilding it again.